# Jest - How to use root slash import with babel-jest?

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, es6-modules, babel-jest

I am using Babel Jest to transpile my code for testing purposes.
I can't get how to use path relative to the project root.

For example, if in a test file I import a module with: `/imports/ui/myModule` Jest throws an error

```
Cannot find module 
'/Users/me/dev/myProject/Users/me/dev/myProject/imports/ui/myModule' from 'test.jsx'`
```

But if I import a module with a relative path like: `../../ui/myModule` it works.

My `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "babel-root-slash-import"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "babel-root-slash-import"
      ],
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react",
        "stage-0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My Jest config is:

```
  "jest": {
    "roots": ["<rootDir>/imports/tests/jest"]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

At instance, you can use [`moduleNameMapper`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) config option.

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "roots": ["<rootDir>/imports/tests/jest"]
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": [
    "^ui/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/imports/ui/$1"
  ]
}

// test.jsx
import myModule from 'imports/ui/myModule';
```

Related answer on SO: [Testing with Jest and Webpack aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629925/testing-with-jest-and-webpack-aliases)

Another example from the `jest`'s official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files